# Modal Dialog not Opening when not authenticated or in incognito mode

Tags: 8

Hi i am using Drupal 8 to render a modal popup on clicking a link. However when i am connected as admin the popup render well but as soon as i logout or choose to be incognito mode of the browser the popup does not appear and the page is redirected to link set in the href tag. Here is my link :

```
<a href="/mysite.com/contact/download_file_advance?nid=371" class="use-ajax" data-dialog-type="modal" data-accepts="application/vnd.drupal-modal" data-filename="Livre Blanc">SOME TEXT IN MODAL</a>
```

Can anyone explain to me why this is so? I can't figure out why when i am connected the modal render well but when not connected it redirect me to the node.

Comment: have you checked your permissions.

Comment: @vijay Where can i chek the permission?

Comment: check it in admin/modules there will be options like configuration, permissions, etc., for each module

Comment: @vijay I am not using any module to display the modal...Infact am using the core module modal provided by drupal 8 itself. I have created a user having role as Authenticated User only but when login using this user also the modal does not appear.

Comment: I think anonymous user is missing the modal library. Either use proper render arrays or add the library via hook_page_attachments

Answer (score 9):

Ajay is correct, the javascript dependencies wont load by default for anonymous users. Here's what I added to my `theme.libraries.yml` to get it working:

```
dependencies: 
  - core/jquery
  - core/drupal.dialog.ajax
```

Comment: I think not just don't load for anonymous; I think they don't load for any non-administrator role.

Comment: This is working for logged in users but not for everyone

Answer (score 4):

For me the only thing that helped beside of hacking PHP code, which in my opinion would be an overkill, was to add the following to the `MY_THEME.info.yml` under the section `libraries`:

```
- 'core/drupal.dialog.ajax'
```

In my case, using a bootstrap based theme, the whole section looked like this:

```
libraries:
  - 'bootstrap_freigeist/global-styling'
  - 'bootstrap_freigeist/bootstrap-scripts'
  - 'core/drupal.dialog.ajax'
```

Be aware that adding the script to the `MY_THEME.libraries.yml` didn't do the trick for me.

Answer (score 2):

For me adding dependencies in libraries.yml did not worked, I am using drupal 8.x version. Below is working solution for me

In your theme file, say your theme name is "abc" then you will have a file "abc.theme", add following code in file. assuming your page alias path is "abcde" where you want to add the dialog box

```
function abc_page_attachments_alter(&$page){
        $current_path = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();
        $path = $current_path = \Drupal::service('path.alias_manager')->getAliasByPath($current_path);
        if($path == '/abcde') {
            $page['#attached']['library'][] = 'core/drupal.ajax';
        }
    }
```

if you want to load library in all pages then replace above function with

```
  function abc_page_attachments_alter(&$page){
                $page['#attached']['library'][] = 'core/drupal.ajax';
        }
```

clear cache and hard refresh your page. dialog box should be working now

Answer (score 1):

The answers posted here are right, also you can include jQuery libraries and the Ajax libraries using *hook_page_attachments*, just implement this function in your ***yourmodule***.module file, replacing the name of your module accordingly, of course:

```
function yourmodule_page_attachments(array &$attachments) {
    $attachments['#attached']['library'][] = 'core/jquery';
    $attachments['#attached']['library'][] = 'core/drupal.dialog.ajax';
}
```

This snippet will add jQuery and Ajax required libraries to all your pages, then you can write your own logic in it if you want to restrict this libraries to only certain pages.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add code dependencies in your theme for ajax and jQuery in your `theme.libraries.yml` file.

Drupal by default does not load ajax for anonymous users.